# How do I convert enum to int in Dictionary key in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose I have an `enum`

```
public enum Countries {
    France, GreatBritain, Japan, CostaRica, ...
}
```

And suppose I have the following action in WebApi Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Dictionary<Countries, int> Get() {
   return new Dictionary<Countries, int> {
      [Countries.France] = 10,
      [Countries.CostaRica] = 50
      ...
   }
}
```

JSON that goes to the client is `"France": 10, "CostaRica": 50`, etc.

I would very much prefer to have `0: 10, 4: 50` instead. Client has no knowledge of the enum values; only the integer index and description (like "France" or "Costa Rica"). I am seeding the database using same enum - so I am confident that IDs match.

I tried different `JsonConverter` options, but they all seem to assume scalar value.

Note: this is a simplified example; real business application is much more complex. Obviously, there is a big benefit to use enum on the server without creating `Dictionary<int, int>` and casting all keys before returning to client. I am pretty sure Json.NET can convert it - I just can figure how to help it.

My application is .NET Core **2.2**; so is this example. I know that 3.0 handles Json.Net slightly differently; but I don't think this converting issue is version-dependent

Comment: With int values you have to cross fingers that the ids will match. With strings you know that they will match.

Comment: As I said, I seed the same enums in the database. So, I **know** that they match :) The problem that the client doesn't have visibility to the strings

Comment: There's an example in the documentation: [Sample factory pattern converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?view=netcore-3.0#sample-factory-pattern-converter): *The following code shows a custom converter that works with `Dictionary<Enum,TValue>`. The code follows the factory pattern because the first generic type parameter is `Enum` and the second is open.*

Comment: thank you, @dbc! I was hoping that I can use one of the "built-in" converters out of the box; but it looks like the answer is "Nope - you need to write your own". If you want to convert (ha-ha) your comment to an answer - I'll accept it.

Comment: *My application is .NET Core 2.2* -- In .Net core 2.2 Json.NET is used so your dictionary should be serialized correctly automatically.  Only in .Net 3.0+ which use `System.Text.Json` might you have problems.

Comment: @dbc - you are correct. In .Net 3.0 I simply used `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` at least for now to not get distracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of casting to int, and return the `ActionResult<Dictionary<int, int>>` which would be something like this :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Dictionary<int, int>> Get() {
   return new Dictionary<Countries, int> {
      [Countries.France] = 10,
      [Countries.CostaRica] = 50
      ...
   }.ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just want to share this, if you need to convert any `Enum` to a Dictionary using Reflection, you can do something like this :

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetEnumAsDictionary<TEnum>() where TEnum : System.Enum
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    var _fields = typeof(TEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    for (int i = 0; i < _fields.Length; i++)
    {
        result.Add(_fields[i].Name, _fields[i].GetRawConstantValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```

usage :

```
var enDic = GetEnumAsDictionary<Countries>();
```

`GetRawConstantValue` returns `object` that's why I made the dictionary value type as an object. but it's easy to bind it to other datatypes or making it generic.

I thought this would be useful to share.

Comment: As I mention in the question, that's exactly what I want to **avoid** (also, I am fine with default values; so not sure what's the purpose of manually overriding)

Comment: Actually, on the second thought, casting to `Dictionary<int, int>` (or really, `Dictionary<string, int>` because the values get quoted, seems to be the best and easiest solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Felix, I have updated my answer with a way to convert `enum` to a dictionary.